# Explain compiled TypeScript namespace (inner working of namespace)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to understand how can namespace be implemented in JavaScript. I'm checking out [How do I declare a namespace in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881515/how-do-i-declare-a-namespace-in-javascript).

One of the answers mentioned the following TypeScript code.

```
namespace Stack {
    export const hello = () => console.log('hi')
}

Stack.hello()
```

is compiled to the following JavaScript

```
var Stack;
(function (Stack) {
    Stack.hello = () => console.log('hi');
})(Stack || (Stack = {}));
```

However, I find it hard to understand the above syntax, could someone explain how does it work? For example, how does the following work?

```
(function(Stack) {...})(...)
(Stack || (Stack = {}))
```

Comment: (Stack || (Stack = {})  means if Stack is undefined or null, set Stack = {} as param. Now inside the function, everything inside will be instantiated with Stack object. 
Like Stack.hello, Stack.whateverExistsInNamespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var Stack;
(function (Stack) {
    Stack.hello = () => console.log('hi');
})(Stack || (Stack = {}));

Stack.hello();
```

It's a self-executing anonymous function. You can check [this document](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-executing-function-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=The%20self%2Dexecuting%20anonymous%20function,a%20trailing%20set%20of%20parenthesis.) for some insights.

For a more understanding version, you can imagine it like below

```js
var Stack;

//naming the function
//`Stack` here is not related to the global `Stack` because the function parameter scopes this variable
function anonymousFunction(Stack) {
    Stack.hello = () => console.log('hi');
}

//replace for `Stack || (Stack = {})`
if(!Stack) {
   Stack = {} //it's a reference value, so if we have any changes inside a function, it will be applied to `Stack` as well
}

//execute the function/namespace to add `hello` to `Stack`
anonymousFunction(Stack); 

Stack.hello();
```

Comment: is Stack || (Stack = {}) saying if Stack has been initialized then use Stack as the argument, otherwise, initialize Stack to {} and use it as the argument?

Comment: actually, it assigned an empty object to Stack if Stack is null, because we cannot assign `hello` to `null` value. You can see the full version of that code in my modified answer. @StephenFong